# Output XML content with unknown node depth using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, recursion

I have paths of information I want to extract from a XML string:

```
"/root/A/info1"
"/root/A/B/info2"
"/root/A/B/info3"
"/root/A/info4"
```

And this is the input:

```
<root>
  <A>
    <info1>value1</info1>
    <B>
      <info2>value2.1</info2>
      <info3>value3.1</info3>
    </B>
    <B>
      <info2>value2.2</info2>
      <!-- note: element "info3" is missing here! -->
    </B>
    <B>
      <info2>value2.3</info2>
      <info3>value3.3</info3>
    </B>
    <info4>value4</info4>
  </A>
 </root>
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
value1|value2.1|value3.1|value4
value1|value2.2|NULL|value4
value1|value2.3|value3.3|value4
```

My paths vary and I never know the depth of the XML file. Because `"/root/A/B/info2"` and `"/root/A/B/info3"` exist three times, I obviously need to output three lines.
I think recursion is needed here.

---

My code:

**main function:**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));   

String[] paths = new String[] {"/root/A/info1", "/root/A/B/info2", "/root/A/B/info3", "/root/A/info4"};

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String[] output = new String[paths.length];

for(int i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
  recursion(paths, doc, xPath, paths[i], i, output);
}
```

**recursive function:**

```
private static void recursion(String[] paths, Object parent, XPath xPath, String path, int position, String[] output) throws Exception {
  if(path.contains("/")) { // check if it's the last element, which contains the needed value
    List<String> pathNodes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(path, "/")));

    String currentPathNode = pathNodes.get(0);

    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(currentPathNode).evaluate(parent, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    pathNodes.remove(0);

    String newPath = StringUtils.join(pathNodes, "/");

    for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = nodeList.item(i);

      recursion(paths, node, xPath, newPath, position, output.clone()); // clone?
    }
  }
  else {
    output[position] = xPath.compile(path).evaluate(parent);

    if((position + 1) == paths.length) { // check if it's the last path, so output the values
      System.out.println(StringUtils.join(output, "|"));
    }
  }
}
```

If I clone `output` I get this:

```
|||value4
```

If I don't clone `output` I get that (overwriting previous values):

```
value1|value2.3|value3.3|value4
```

Please give me a hint.

**Update:** Have again a look at the XML input. Text elements which have no value could be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

I added a context path to my application. It specifies which element is the deepest.

In my example here it would be `"/root/A/B"`.

I update all my paths to be relative to that context path:

```
"../info1"
"info2"
"info3"
"../info4"
```

Then I count the nodes from the context path (here `3`). That's also the number of lines that will be created. I create a loop to iterate over them and query my updated paths with XPath.